# Move columns in CSV with batch or powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, batch-file

I'm using MediaInfo CLI version in Win 7 x64 to automatically make a CSV via template when a video file has finished encoding in StaxRip.
However, its CLI version is critical about how to apply the output template (long story short, its variables are in sections (general, video, audio, text) and you can only use one section in one block, you can't go back to a previous section further down the template), so one variable that I want elsewhere has to end up in the wrong spot for the automation to even work.

Like this:

```
UTC 2015-05-21 18:04:06,Episode01.mp4,211 MiB,22mn 7s,29.970 fps,1 210 Kbps,High 10@L3,120 Kbps,AAC,Japanese
UTC 2015-05-21 19:16:18,Episode02.mp4,211 MiB,22mn 6s,29.970 fps,1 212 Kbps,High 10@L3,118 Kbps,AAC,Japanese
UTC 2015-05-21 20:24:57,Episode03.mp4,211 MiB,22mn 6s,29.970 fps,1 212 Kbps,High 10@L3,119 Kbps,AAC,Japanese
```

What I'm looking for is the timestamp portion (first column) to become the LAST column instead:

```
Episode01.mp4,211 MiB,22mn 7s,29.970 fps,1 210 Kbps,High 10@L3,120 Kbps,AAC,Japanese,UTC 2015-05-21 18:04:06
```

I would very much love to find a solution to this in a .bat or Powershell script if possible since these are already used in the aforementioned process, but am open to small single-purpose applications. The crucial part is being able to be run from CMD or from a master .bat file.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. You should try to learn PowerShell or batch yourself and if you run into a problem, you can post your code here to get help with a specific issue. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: My bad. I rather wanted to be pointed in the right direction of what I needed to look into specifically within batch or PS, but I see your point. Will keep in mind in case of further questions.

Comment: I understand, but asking for recommendations is specifically off-topic here. Nothing wrong with that, this just isn't the place for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this one out and is working.

```
[string] $SourceFileFullPath = "C:\Projects\INT\CSV_ColumnSwap.csv"
[Array] $SourceFileContent = Get-Content $SourceFileFullPath

[int] $ArrayLength = $SourceFileContent.length  
for ($i=0; $i -lt $ArrayLength; $i++) {
        $splitter1 = ","
        $LineData = $SourceFileContent[$i] -split $splitter1
        $DateTimeV, $Linedata = $LineData
        $LineData += $DateTimeV     
        $LineData -join "," >> Result.csv
}
```

I am not particularly sure about the performance aspects. YMMV.

Cheers

Comment: Worked wonders, many many thanks! Now I just need to figure out how it works and why. :)